# Mesh Opacity issue when the mesh is invisible

Tags: three.js

I have created a jsfiddle [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/5/ ] to demo the issue.

The scene have a red cube and a number of particle inside that cube. Here the steps to reproduce the issue.

1) Set the cube as invisible by unchecking the visible checkbox in the control pannel.

2) Rotate the cube

3) Increase the opacity via the opacity control in the pannel

4) Set the cube as visible.

Now the cube would have become completely opaque. I have observed that the issue is not consistent but used to occur most of the time for me.

Is this a bug in the API or is there any issue in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparency is hit-and-miss in webGL. In your case, your transparent objects are competing with each other. One solution is to set the transparency of your particles to `false` in your `shaderMaterial`, so there is only the single transparent cube. Everything works in that case.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfrsj/6/

Comment: So does that mean that only mesh can be set as transparent in a scene. I need to deal with a situation to set more than one mesh to be transparent at a time. How to deal with such a case ?

Comment: You can have multiple transparent objects and you can control the order of rendering by setting `renderer.sortObjects = false`. If you want to pursue this, I'd suggest you study `webGLRenderer.js` so you really understand how transparency is handled by three.js.